# Native php session $_SESSION in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel doesn't use the native php session since Laravel 5.0. So I was wondering if it was OK to use $_SESSION as an expire_on_close session in Laravel app along with remember_on_close session().

Comment: Don't. There's good reason why Laravel opted to not use the PHP session and one of the major disadvantages is that the native PHP session does not allow concurrent requests from the same user. You should instead just persist the session parts you want remembered in the database or a long term key value store/cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $_SESSION in laravel, if you want use session in laravel, you can see the following below or [session in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session)

```html
//put value session
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

//get value session
 $value = $request->session()->get('key');
 
 //Retrieving All Session Data
 $data = $request->session()->all();
 
 //check session return true, if correct
 if ($request->session()->has('key')) {
    //
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Laravel **[session global helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#retrieving-data)**.

To set the session data, use:

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

To retrieve the session data, use:

```
$value = session('key');
//output: value
```