# How to share session between a native php application and a laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies

I have a native PHP application which has the login. I need to use that session from the Laravel application.
My PHP app runs on : localhost:80
While my Laravel app runs on localhost:8000

I have tried to set the same session name in both and changed the session driver to 'cookie' in the laravel app. but no success. Then set it to 'native'. Nothing worked. Is there a way to do that.

Comment: Because they are on different ports they have separate sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to share session between servers. Browsers wont share cookies between websites, so the session id wont be shared.

Anyway Laravel doesn't use using php's native session. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513544/native-php-session-session-in-laravel)

Comment: Cant we share the session between apps in the same domain?